# Pricing for AWS Application Load Balancer VS Nginx load balancer setup on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

My question here is either I have to go for AWS Application load balancer or nginx or haproxy load balancer setup on AWS EC2 instance? I am more concern about pricing and can not afford downtime.

Need to make up a couple of load scenarios - low, medium, high and work out a price point for each in aws appication load balancer vs nginx on ec2 instance.

Can anyone suggest best use cases based on your experience?

Answer (score 4):

EC2:

1. Maintaining is up to you (updates, security etc.).
2. Autoscaling is up to you.
3. Pricing is {your_desired_instance_type_cost} * 24h * 31 days (1month) PLUS:

- Data-transfer costs
- Volumes costs

ELB:

1. Don't care about maintaining.
2. Don't care about autoscaling.
3. Base Pricing is 0.0252$ * 24h * 31 days (1month) ~= 18,74$/month PLUS:

- Data-transfer costs
- LCU (Load Balancer Capacity Units) cost
- Additional costs for 10+ load balancer rules

For ELB calculations you can try this [AWS ELB calculator](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/)

For EC2 + Nginx you can use [AWS Pricing Calculator](https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator/EC2)

From my experience - go for ELB. You set this up once and don't even care about anything else. It's easy to configure (IaC), it has 99.95% uptime (you won't get similar with ec2+nginx), and it's not so expensive. Additionally you can attach AWS WAF to ELB now, and you can easly point your CloudFront distribution to ELB.

Comment: You can automate EC2 autoscaling using AWS.  And automatically patch the EC2 instances inside an [AWS Systems Manager maintenance window](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-maintenance.html) - but I guess that will be a disruptive operation and result in some downtime.  Maybe a better solution is to rather automate the creation of new AMIs, with up-to-date patches, that you then deploy to your [ASG](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html).

Comment: You might also just want to evaluate how SSL certificates and their renewal works in Nginx.  If you create your SSL certificate in AWS with [ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) and its attached to an ELB, AWS will [auto-renew](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/managed-renewal.html) it for you.  The EC2+Nginx might be cheaper when its up and running but it will require a lot of development effort...

Comment: Here I understand your point. But mainly I want to know any use case where you have seen like in this case EC2 or ALB charges are high or low.

Comment: Charges depends on your usage. If your traffic is low, but you transfer alot of data - then you'll pay for data-transfers alot (EC2 and ALB). And "high or low" charges depends what means "high" or "low" for you. If your traffic is high, then propably your EC2+Nginx will scale UP, same as ALB, so you will pay more for EC2, like for ALB. In calculators you can put very specific data, like `Average number of requests per second per ALB` - and you will get costs. EC2+Nginx charges are smaller if your time has no value - but how much? You have to calculate it.

Comment: I asked someone about this: They said the `nginx` instance is very low on resource usage.  That you can probably get away with using a small (say `t4g.small`) for medium traffic ("if you are just `proxy_passing`").  For pet projects you can just run in on your application server - you don't even need to spin up another server.  I guess if your security groups are set up and its just web traffic you probably don't need to be overly concerned with patching the server.

Comment: Going to try this out for myself as well.  ALB costs seems excessive, but I guess you don't always need to spin it up in all your environments (dev, qa, etcetera) if you can access your servers in other ways.

Comment: @CloudNinja sounds like 1 instance, and sounds like it have nothing to do with High-Availability (EC2 instances can go down, ASG will set up another one, but still you're out for 2-5mins). OP said about `and can not afford downtime`

Comment: The reason the server is so small is because it probably just points the traffic to the end destination (application server) and the majority of the traffic then communicates directly with the application server which might be bigger and be able to handle that network traffic.  Still, feel free to encapsulate the EC2 instance in an ASG with a launch template for flexibility

Comment: Btw. this small instance still costs about 12,5$/month (without reservation/spot). If you want to set up minimal HA, you have to put at least 2 instances, which gives you 25$/month. Base cost for ALB 18,74$/month is really really cheap for what it gives (HA, WAF/CloudFront integrations etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think that more traffic should be directly proportional to more money ingress by your site, so don't be afraid of the traffic ingress. Of course, you will pay more in AWS but you will have fewer headaches when a problem comes and downtime.
Just imagine you put all of your efforts now. Then the design complexity increases because of traffic volume. After that you think "well at this point I think I need some help" ...but you are at EC2, more difficult to scale without downtime. Also may be your knowledge about devops doesnt let you solve the problem quickly.